# kubectl scale removing pods with latest image and keeping old ones

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

So I have a deployment job that runs some kubectl commands.
A configuration file is modified to use the latest docker image SHA, and I run these commands to deploy it out:

```
kubectl apply -f myconfig-file.yaml
#we have to scale up temporarily due to reasons beyond the purview of this question
kubectl scale -f myconfig-file.yaml --replicas=4
#* wait a minute or so *
sleep 60
kubectl scale -f myconfig-file.yaml --replicas=2
```

Apply correctly updates the replicationcontroller definition on Google Cloud to be pointed at the latest image, but the original containers still remain. Scaling up DOES create containers with the correct image, but once I scale down, it removes the newest containers, leaving behind the old containers with the old image.

I have confirmed that:

1. The new containers with their new image are working as expected.
2. I ended up doing the deployment manually and manually removed the old containers, (and k8s correctly created two new containers with the latest image) and when I scaled down, the new containers with the new images stuck around.  My application worked as expected.

My yaml file in question:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: my-app-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-app-cluster
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mySuperCoolImage@sha256:TheLatestShaHere
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: my-app-cluster
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8008
          protocol: TCP
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

I'm using the Google Cloud K8s FWIW. Do I need to do something in the YAML file to instruct k8s to destroy the old instances?

Comment: I think [ReplicationController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) is a very old object, and not the current approach to deploying things.  Do you mean to use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) instead?

Comment: I saw that replication controller is outdated, but the project  I inherited is using it. We plan to move it to something else, just not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the majority of my problem stem from the fact that I'm using a `ReplicationController` instead of a more supported `Deployment` or a `ReplicaSet`. Unfortunately, at this time, I'll need to consult with my team on the best way to migrate to that format since there are some considerations we have.

In the meantime, I fixed the issue with this little hack.

```
oldPods=($(kubectl get pods | grep myPodType | perl -wnE'say /.*-myPodType-\w*/g'))

#do the apply and scale thing like listed above
#then delete
for item in ${oldPods[@]}; do kubectl delete pod $item; done
```

Answer (score 0):

when you update deployment definition with new image tag, you do not need to scale up/down. Deployment should start new pods and delete pods with old image on it's own, using scaling only complicates the process, and as you noticed it does not take the pod spec change into account when it decides which pods to delete.

Comment: I noticed that even when I do not scale, the other pods arent deleted and replaced with new pods. I end up having to do that manually with the current setup. The scale process is required due to reasons beyond the purview of the question.

Comment: if you need *all* the new pods to scale up first and then donscale old ones, you'd do better with implementing blue/green pattern for deployment. Have to separate deployments that you scale independent of each other.

As for the fact that deploys do not roll out upgrade correctly, do you have PDBs implemented ?

Comment: We do not, but I found an alternate solution that I'm going to detail in my answer below.